# In the Wizarding World, is flying without a broom or other object/creature, a dark art?

Tags: harry-potter, dark-arts

In book 7, Harry and several members of the Order of the Phoenix seem to be shocked / surprised that Voldemort can fly without transfiguring or without the aid of a broom or enchanted object (motorbike, car, etc...) or a magical creature (Thestral).

Does this mean that flying (a'la 'Superman') is a dark art / what would inherently be dark about doing so?

Comment: I cordially disagree w/ the vote to close that this would be opinion based, because since there is an entire class devoted to 'defense against the dark arts' - there are distinct and knowable dark arts. (ie - it isn't an opinion that X or Y is a dark art). Also, considering that a group of extremely advanced and 'good' wizards were surprised at such a thing, Voldemort being the only one known to do so, it seems reasonable to consider that it is. But - I'm looking for canon / word of god evidence as such

Comment: In the movies, flying without brooms looks like "dark art" because only death eaters are seen flying like this and they always leave a trace of dark fog/mist.

Comment: @Zanon That’s actually the on-screen way of showing Death Eaters Apparating. The company that created the special effects called it “Death Eater Apparition”, never flight. *We had the task of creating the deatheater apparation effect. The Death Eaters were to arrive from the sky amongst an amorphous spear of smoke, stabbing into the ground and suddenly taking form amongst tendrils of this acrid black smoke. The black smoke needed to encircle the Death Eaters bodies, becoming the black of their swirling cloaks as they materialized.* [- Syflex website](http://www.syflex.biz/gallery_dneg1.html)

Comment: @Bellatrix, thanks for the source for movie 4, but in movie 6, they seem to be [flying through London](https://youtu.be/Mo-U5iOinM8?t=31s). The bridge twists as they pass by.

Comment: @Zanon I have seen that, and I’m fairly sure it’s still supposed to be the same thing (though it *does* look more like flying than Apparition).

Comment: Amusing side note: in the fanfic Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality, it's explained that the way Voldemort does this is by placing the broomstick-flying spell on his bones. http://www.hpmor.com/chapter/107 This is part of that story's general thrust that both Harry and Voldemort are good at thinking "rationally" outside the box of tradition.

Comment: yes. I have no canon quotes, but that's why this is a comment not an answer. I have a quote from somewhere (I don't remember where) that says, "Voldemort's ability to fly is most certainly of Dark Origins" Maybe Pottermore?

Comment: @Domenic check your sources, this is not a reliable source. Try Pottermore or JKR interviews. Mine is, I believe, from Pottermore, but I cannot be sure, hence why I have a comment.

Comment: Yes, I'd hope that was obvious when I included the adjective "fanfic".

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## Not necessarily - it’s just very unusual, so no one expected it.

The Order of the Phoenix likely is just surprised because flying without a broom is considered nearly, if not completely, impossible. Quidditch Through the Ages, a popular book among wizards detailing the history of Quidditch, says there’s no spell invented that allows a wizard to fly unaided in human form. The Dark Lord, however, does exactly that. That would surprise anyone who, knowing this, considered flying without a broom something that was currently not possible.

> “No spell yet devised enables wizards to fly unaided in human form. Those few Animagi who transform into winged creatures may enjoy flight, but they are a rarity.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

J.K. Rowling also clarified this in a tweet, where she says only the most gifted wizards can do it, and it’s very risky so few would attempt it. It’s not described as being Dark magic, just hard to do.

> @jk_rowling @bluesrgt So would that work the same for brooms? Would more advanced wizards/witches not need a broom to fly?
>
> Exactly. Wands and brooms (and flying cars) are tools that channel magic. The most gifted can dispense with them. 
> <sub><sup>*[J.K. Rowling on Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/707226426274086912?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.elitedaily.com%2Fentertainment%2Fjk-rowling-why-voldemort-fly%2F1412777)*</sup></sub>

She explains that it’s not something the average wizard could do.

> *@jk_rowling Are there many wizards/witches at Hogwarts who can do magic and fly without wands or brooms?*
>
> .@DreamingOfMagic No, there's a cultural tradition of using wands and broomless flight is (as you might imagine) very risky! 
> <sub><sup>*[J.K. Rowling on Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/707227439500562432?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.elitedaily.com%2Fentertainment%2Fjk-rowling-why-voldemort-fly%2F1412777)*</sup></sub>

Nothing is ever mentioned about it being Dark magic, just difficult magic.

Comment: It may be that nothing is ever mentioned about it being Dark magic per se, but I seem to remember McGonagall saying about snape something along the lines of he seems to have picked up some tricks from his new master. I agree with this answer :) and it gets my +1, but i certainly don't blame the op for wondering. it does seem like death eater magic from its very limited portrayal on screen

Comment: @Au101 McGonagall did say that about Snape - it’s a logical conclusion whether or not it’s Dark magic. Snape worked with the Dark Lord, likely the only other one she knew who could, so it’s likely Snape learned it from the Dark Lord. Yes, it is a good question, the answer is just ‘it’s probably not Dark magic’.

Comment: Snape transfigured / animagused into a bat though, didn't he? Not just jumped out a window and flew away like Iron Man

Comment: @NKCampbell It seems he did just jump out the window. *“No, he’s not dead,’ said McGonagall bitterly. ‘Unlike Dumbledore, he was still carrying a wand … and he seems to have learned a few tricks from his master.’ With a tingle of horror, Harry saw in the distance a huge, bat-like shape flying through the darkness towards the perimeter wall.”* He’s said to be batlike but I think it’s his robe.
*“Our Headmaster is taking a short break,’ said Professor McGonagall, pointing at the Snape-shaped hole in the window.” - Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 30 (The Sacking of Severus Snape)*

Comment: I don’t really understand why JKR would say that broomless flight would be very risky. If anything, being hampered by having use one hand to hold on to a large, inanimate object between your legs would seem to me to pose much more of a risk. Broomless flight would surely be safer than broomed flight, generally speaking.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It’s probably because they won’t have the broom to support them - if they lose control of their magic, they’ll start to fall. With a broom, it would help keep them up and it’d likely take less conscious effort to stay up.

Comment: Perhaps… though I’d think if they lost control of their magic, the broom would also just start to fall, with the same result.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet A Nimbus is not just a stick. It's magic-powered airplane that's conveniently disguised as a broom. Your argumentation can be compared to saying that controlling a car is more difficult than controlling a skateboard because car keeps your hands on the steering wheel and that's hampering you. It's the opposite: the wheel is specifically designed to make it easier to steer using it rather than balancing your body.

Answer (score 7):

I would say not as Harry flew onto his school roof in the first book, with unintentional magic.

> Dudley's gang had been chasing him as normal when, as much to Harry's surprise as anyone else's, there he was sitting on the chimney. The Dursleys had received a very angry letter from Harry's headmistress telling them Harry had been climbing school buildings. But all he'd tried to do (as he shouted at Uncle Vernon through the locked door of his cupboard) was jump behind the big bins outside the kitchen doors. Harry supposed that the wind must have caught him in mid-jump.
>   <sub>*(Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 2, The Vanishing Glass)*.</sub>

He also allowed Aunt Marge to 'fly' (in a manner).

These did not raise any questions about Dark magic and were dealt with as being quite commonplace.

Comment: He flew? I don't have the quotes right away, but from what I remember it was kind of implied that he Apparated there. As for both your examples, not wrong, but those are "uncontrolled" magic. I think OP was looking for _intended_ broomless flight.

Comment: @Jenayah Apparition seems very unlikely for the school incident. The side effects of Apparating (queasiness, feeling like you’re being squashed through a tube, reeling afterwards) are described as being unpleasant enough to put many wizards off Apparition as a means of transportation altogether, and the school incident is described along the lines of “the next thing he knew, he was on the roof, with no idea how he got there”. That doesn’t sound like he went through Apparition. A moment of flight (self-directed _Wingardium Leviosa_, perhaps) seems more likely.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree that Apparition is a bit much, but still, wouldn't he remember takiing off and flying? Maybe there is some kind of kid's magic-Apparition thingy, ahah. Uncontrolled magic seems really random sometimes...

Comment: I remembered the book as saying he thought the wind had carried him up there.

Comment: Fantastic example! I never would have thought of it but it's legit I think.

Comment: kids don't have any control over the magic they do prior to Hogwarts though, its even said in the books that parents are expected to control their children and ensure that they don't do magic accidentally in front of muggles, stay safe, etc...A Dark "art" by definition is a learned behavior. Thus, even if Harry flew accidentally, he never did again, and he didn't learn an 'art' of flying. (This isn't to say I disagree that it isn't a dark art, just that accidental use of magic != dark art). Upvote for a great example

Comment: I agree with the conclusion, but not the basis. Tom Riddle did Dark magic before Hogwarts and also didn’t seem to be caught. *“And as you saw, they were not the random experiments typical of young wizards: he was already using magic against other people, to frighten, to punish, to control. The little stories of the strangled rabbit and the young boy and girl he lured into a cave were most suggestive … I can make them hurt if I want to …” - Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 13 (The Secret Riddle)* This seems to be, as Snape told Lily because “they let you off when you’re a kid”.

Comment: A little magic in his jump is not flying.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that they think it is a Dark Art. It is that it is something that probably was never heard of before. Like airbenders being able to fly by themselves without gliders or a wand casting unknown spells of its own volition.

Comment: Can you [edit] in why you think this? I.e. why do you think it’s never been heard of before?

Comment: because of people's reaction to Voldemort flying by himself and in all the books there was never any mention of wizards flying without a magical object.